# How can I use context in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I made Entity models in MVC, in model first approach, and I would like to know, how to insert, delete, and modify data.

I try to use

```
namespace EntityFrameworkModelFirst
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class ModelFirstContainer : DbContext
    {
        public ModelFirstContainer()
            : base("name=ModelFirstContainer")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();

        }

        public virtual DbSet<Department> DepartmentSet { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> EmployeeSet { get; set; }
    }

    using (var context = new ModelFirstContainer()) 
    {     
    // Perform data access using the context 
    }

}
```

But, it makes error to me. The error is: The contextual word 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code, and missing ;.
Is it valid now? Where can i do this? Which files?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using block must be in a method. You can't have it outside of a method. Also, I've removed your OnModelCreating which would have thrown an exception.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace EntityFrameworkModelFirst
{   
    public partial class ModelFirstContainer : DbContext
    {
        public ModelFirstContainer() : base("name=ModelFirstContainer")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Department> DepartmentSet { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> EmployeeSet { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public void DoSomeStuff()
        {
             using (var context = new ModelFirstContainer()) 
             {     
                 // Perform data access using the context 
             }
        }
    }
}
```

A [using block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is used with [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects to ensure they get properly disposed. `ModelFirstContainer` inherits from `DbContext` which implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial on how to work with the Entity Framework DbContext can be found here: [Working with DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx)

```
    public class ProductContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}

using (var context = new ProductContext()) 
{     
    // Perform data access using the context 
}
```

Comment: You should not answer questions that are too broad or that do not have a clear problem.